# Adjusting the end dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, window-functions

I wanted to manipulate the end date to next record startdate or records that happened on same day for shopID and then grab the starttime of later record and update the value in the prior row endtime if the starttime prior to next row start time and end date crosses the next record start date.

For example (ShopId: 9856) end date of first record is '2020-01-08 09:18:52' which is crosses the start time of next record '2020-01-08 09:09:48'. Here my logic need to look for such instances happen on same day and manipulate the enddate of first record to next record startdate

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTab1](
StoreID [int] NOT NULL,
PurchaseID [int] NOT NULL,
ShopID [int] NOT NULL,
LocationID [int] NOT NULL,
starttime [datetime] NOT NULL,
Endtime [datetime] NOT NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [TestTab1]
VALUES
(1020,20200102,9856,0010,'2020-01-08T09:08:53','2020-01-08T09:18:52'),
(1021,20200102,9856,0020,'2020-01-08T09:09:48','2020-01-08T09:11:52'),
(1022,20200102,9856,0030,'2020-01-08T09:12:53','2020-01-08T09:14:52'),
(1023,20200102,9856,0040,'2020-01-08T09:16:48','2020-01-08T09:18:52')
```

Final Result set:

```
StoreID |PurchaseID |ShopID |LocationID |starttime           |Endtime
--------|-----------|-------|-----------|--------------------|-------------------
1020    |20200102   |9856   |10         |2020-01-08 09:08:53 |2020-01-08 09:09:48
1021    |20200103   |9856   |20         |2020-01-08 09:09:48 |2020-01-08 09:11:52
1022    |20200102   |9856   |30         |2020-01-08 09:12:53 |2020-01-08 09:14:52
1023    |20200104   |9856   |40         |2020-01-08 09:16:48 |2020-01-08 09:18:52
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lead()` and conditional logic:

```
select storeid, purchaseid, shopid, locationid, starttime,
    case when endtime > lead(starttime) over(partition by shopid, convert(date, starttime) order by starttime)
        then lead(starttime) over(partition by shopid, convert(date, starttime) order by starttime)
        else endtime
    end endtime
from testtab1
```

Moving the window calculation to a subquery makes the query a bit more readable:

```
select storeid, purchaseid, shopid, locationid, starttime,
    case when endtime > lead_starttime then lead_starttime else endtime end endtime
from (
    select t.*, lead(starttime) over(partition by shopid, convert(date, starttime) order by starttime) lead_starttime
    from testtab1 t
) t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ba4f52964b7cb625043f8d824c87f647)**:

```
storeid | purchaseid | shopid | locationid | starttime               | endtime                
------: | ---------: | -----: | ---------: | :---------------------- | :----------------------
   1020 |   20200102 |   9856 |         10 | 2020-01-08 09:08:53.000 | 2020-01-08 09:09:48.000
   1021 |   20200102 |   9856 |         20 | 2020-01-08 09:09:48.000 | 2020-01-08 09:11:52.000
   1022 |   20200102 |   9856 |         30 | 2020-01-08 09:12:53.000 | 2020-01-08 09:14:52.000
   1023 |   20200102 |   9856 |         40 | 2020-01-08 09:16:48.000 | 2020-01-08 09:18:52.000
```

Comment: Thanks for sending the detailed logic. I have few edges cases where the enddatetimes are null and in this scenario I would like the value to default to end of business day datetime by looking at starttime of that respective transaction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is effectively the same solution as GMB, but they were quicker at written an answer than I, and I use a CTE as I feel it's more readable over multiple `LEAD`s:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT TT.StoreID,
           TT.PurchaseID,
           TT.ShopID,
           TT.LocationID,
           TT.starttime,
           TT.Endtime,
           LEAD(TT.startTime,1,Endtime) OVER (ORDER BY StartTime ASC) AS NextstartTime
    FROM dbo.TestTab1 TT)
SELECT C.StoreID,
       C.PurchaseID,
       C.ShopID,
       C.LocationID,
       C.starttime,
       CASE WHEN C.Endtime > C.NextstartTime THEN C.NextstartTime ELSE ISNULL(C.Endtime,DATEADD(MILLSECOND,-3,DATEADD(DAY,1,CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(date,C.starttime))))) END AS EndTime
FROM CTE C;
```

Comment: Thanks for sending the detailed logic. I have few edges cases where the enddatetimes are null and in this scenario I would like the value to default to end of business day datetime by looking at starttime of that respective transaction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should include that logic in your question, @John , along with examples. Also, when is the end of the business date? `23:59.59.9999999`? `17:00:00`? Does it vary by day?

Comment: End of the business date here would be "23:59.59.9999999". Thanks!

Comment: It's a guess, due to no new sample data, but updated, @John .

Comment: .... Wait, @John, you state above that "where the enddatetimes are null" but you **explicitly** define your column as `NOT NULL`. It *can't* have `NULL` values...